# Is there a fluid not following the communicating vessel effect?

Tags: fluid-statics

Some substances (I tested a mixture of cement and water, but I believe it works also with spackling paste for example),can behave as a fluid in the preparation container. That is, they form a flat surface due their own weight.

But when poured carefully in a U-tube, (or a pipe with elbows at the ends) it is possible to fill completely one branch, without the material reach the same level at the other side. It is an example of what we could call static pressure loss. Even staying there for several minutes (until starts to harden), the communicating vessel effect doesn't happen.

But they are mixtures, could be called colloids I suppose. Is it possible to observe the same effect on a fluid with only one phase? I think of a viscous liquid as melted glass for example.